# Chaining functions directly to function(){}

Tags: javascript, function

So ever once in a while, just for fun, I check out the source of Facebook to find all kinds of  crazy javascript.

So in the keyup of the textarea on the facebook chat, i found:

```
Bootloader.loadComponents(["control-textarea"], function () {
    TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)
}.bind(this));
```

This didn't seem to interest me until I relized that `.bind()` is added directly to that function.

I didn't know you can do that.

Can any function be after to another `function(){}` just like that? Or is there a special way you need to do this.

I know you can chain stuff like `"How are you doing!".replace(/\w{3}/g,'').toUpperCase()`, but didn't think you chain directly to the `function(){}` itself.

Comment: You aren't "chaining" the `function() {}` call, you're chaining the `.loadComponents()` call.

Comment: They "chain" the function inside `.loadComponents()`. `function () {
    TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)
}.bind(this)`

Comment: @Blender: not according to the parenthesis order. It appears loadComponents is being passed two args. An array, and an anon function with a chained bind call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is a  property available on Function objects in ES5 environments, or where `.bind` has been added to `Function.prototype`. It's just like any other property available on an object or via the prototype chain.

The `.bind` method returns a new function with its calling context *(and arguments if provided)* permanently bound to that new function. The new function invokes the code body of the original function, so aside from the bound context and args, the behavior is otherwise the same.

Comment: Oh, see i didn't even know you can do `Function.prototype`, i only knew of using prototype with `String`, `Number`, `Array`, and `Date`. Thanks

Comment: @Shawn31313: You're welcome. Yes, functions in JavaScript are just another type of object. They're unique in that they're a *callable* object, but in most other respects, they're very much like any other object. You can add properties to them. That's how for example `jQuery` can be both a function, and a namespace. `$("foobar")` and `$.extend()` are both valid, even though `$` is a function. There are other commonly used properties of `Function.prototype`, like `.call` and `.apply`.

Comment: Oh yeah, actually I get it now, since when I attach $ to something im not suppose to I get an error and it says this function cant be attached to the function i tried to attach it. Well thanks. ^_^

Comment: @Shawn31313: I really have no idea what you mean. If `$` is a function, unless something like `Object.freeze` has been called on it, you can attach properties directly to the function object. `var $ = function() {alert("$");}; $.foo = function() {alert("$.foo");};` http://jsfiddle.net/9gaSQ/